# Decrypting an image-based cipher I found online

Tags: cipher, visual

My buddy shared an image with me that has the following characters (above which are written interpretations my friend came up with). I have no idea what it says, but we're interested in finding out (hopefully not weird or offensive, but either way). It's a bit difficult to make out the letters, but going off the fact some repeat, it seems like it could be a basic replacement cipher. We're not totally convinced. To be clear, I'm asking what the characters in this screenshot say.

[image: Image with unknown characters]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! A picture of a picture isn't really helpful - we can't tell what the characters are. Could you provide a transcription?

Comment: That's fair, but I have no idea how to. Can't identify the characters or what they'd be in unicode.

Comment: I tried a reverse image search on Google, no dice.  Any clue what game it's from (assuming that's a game)?

Comment: Is it rot13(Znexre Flzobyf) from rot13(Qrnq Fcnpr)?  Looks similar...

Comment: It was found in the wild in vrchat, so says my friend.

Comment: Letters are matching up, so yeah I think that's the alphabet.  The picture is really hard to read though.  I'll give it a shot :)

Answer (score 3):

To solve, use the following:

> Marker Symbols alphabet from Dead Space

Translation (with added punctuation):

> Report Number Thirty Four

> The following is the letter of caution for you and the scientists working with the sample.  Take heed of this warning and take the percautions (sic) listed in the following report.  It is very crucial for this to work correctly for your advanced studies.  The bioweapons department has issued a warning to to (sic) all staff as another precaution too (sic?) please take every step ou (sic) can with time and patience and remember to take the dosage that I sent beforehand before exposing yourself to the sample.

> Regards

> UCS Specialist Rameriz (sic?)